# When i try to move something the object does not move and it moves a yellow dot

Tags: objects, transforms

I'm trying to move a object but it does not move with the move tool and instead a yellow dot moves.
It does it with every object even one that I just add. I am new to blender so its probably something I accidently pressed that did it but I have tried reopening it.

Answer (score 4):

If it's because you accidently checked something; it's probably because you checked "Transform affect only Locations" in the Options drop down menu, or otherwise set that flag.

[image]

Comment: Thank you it worked